# try, except block concatenate each spot in a list to some combined string variable

Tags: python, string, list, try-except

link_strings(xs): Consider a sequence of values, xs. It can contain any python values, but we're only interested in the strings. Without using the type() function, just try concatenate each spot in the list to some sort of combined_string variable, and figure out how to pass over each failed (non-string) concatenation along the way.
• Parameter: xs :: list of values.
• Return value: a string as the concatenation of all strings in xs.
• Requirement: you must use try-except blocks in your solution! Do not use type().

```
    def link_strings(xs):
        string1 = ''
        try:
            for i in range(len(xs)):
                 string1 += xs[i]
            return string1
        except:
```

The problem I am having is what to actually put in my except block so that if there are any other values that are not strings to pass over them and combine only the string values and if there aren't any then to return an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
def link_strings(xs):
        string1 = ''
        for i in range(len(xs)):
            try:
                string1 += str(xs[i])
            except:
                print "not a string"
        return string1
```

Note that this will happily covert floats and ints to strings. (credit:  SiHa)

Comment: Note that this will happily covert `float`s and `int`s to `str`s. Whether this is what the OP wants, of course, is anyone's guess.

Comment: you are right, i did that bacause he said `Without using the type() function`   so i think there is no other way, i will add your note to the answer